# Comparing timestamps from two fields in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to compare two fields in MySQL database containing timestamps and return `TRUE` if the timestamp in the second field is greater than the timestamp in the first field, otherwise return `FALSE`.
Both fields were filled using `NOW()` SQL function.

So what is the best method of doing this? Should I retrieve timestamps from both fields and then compare them in PHP script or what am I supposed to do?

Thanks guys...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare elapsed time between datetime fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262556/how-to-compare-elapsed-time-between-datetime-fields)

Comment: I think it can be done using pure mysql.

Answer (score 2):

I think doing it like this is better than executing 2 queries.

```
SELECT IF(time1 < time2, true, false) FROM `table` WHERE id = 1
```

[MySQL `IF()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)